# Laravel 5 Updating record returns false

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, collections

When I try to update record in db it doesn't update and it 
`returns false`.

I can't understand what to pass as image position in

```
$product->images()->update();
```

I can't use `ids` as search criteria, I must `update` by image index.

```
<?php
if (isset($product->images[$key])) {
    $result = $product->images[$key]->update([
        'name' => $filename
    ]);
    dd($result);
} else {
    $product->images()->create([
        'name' => $filename
    ]);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't define the `name` field as mass assignable in the `$fillable` in your Images model. Go to your Images model and define this property:

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Please read my answer again. In your ```Image``` model, did you define the ```$fillable``` property?

Comment: Script I have uploads new images but doesn't update existing ones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628597/get-item-from-collection-by-index-laravel-5