# Get item from collection by index Laravel 5

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I need to upload multiple images to server. If image exists in database update name, upload new. Else create new record in database.
Script I have uploads new images but doesn't update existing ones.

```
if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
    foreach ($request->file('images') as $key => $image) {
        $filename = time() . $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move('img/products', $filename);

        if (isset($product->images[$key])) {
            $result = $product->images[$key]->update([
                'name' => $filename
            ]);
            dd($result);
        } else {
            $product->images()->create([
                'name' => $filename
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should show your input form also so we can understand what type of request is coming

Comment: What does `$product` OR how fill it with collection?

Comment: input type file. What else?

Comment: What is a relation between Product and Image ? you get images of the product using the array keys, This is not true.

Comment: Product hasMany images, image belongsTo product

Comment: @NgoliChiganu No i mean how do you name your input field ? $key is id of your images or only number

Comment: Input name is images. Key is number of input, if second input was used - update second image in db

Comment: I have 4 input fields for images

Answer (score 2):

Use [`updateOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#other-creation-methods) method instead of the whole `if ... else` clause:

```
$product->images->updateOrCreate(['id' => $key], ['name' => $filename]);
```

Comment: Is is index of input file, not for id

Comment: Key is number of input, if second input was used - update second image in db

Comment: @NgoliChiganu in your code you're usinig `$key` as `id`. If it's not an ID, what is ID? If you don't have one how do you want to find out does this file already exist in DB or not?

Comment: Are you stupid?? I told you $key is index of input, I can get image using $product->images[$key] but it refuses to update it.

Comment: @NgoliChiganu I don't think you even know about basic coding and you are working on laravel and saying someone stupid while you are stupid who didn't know how to manage a simple form

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the wonderfull collection methods laravel has to check if an collection contains a specific item / key. Please take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-get to retrieve an item by key from a collection. If the item does not exists null will be returned. You can make a check something like

```
if(null !== $product->images()->get($key)){
    // update
    // remove old image
} else {
    // create
}
```

You can also remove the old image from your server when you are in the update method.

Answer (score 1):

It should be done like this

```
if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
        foreach ($request->file('images') as $key => $image) {
            $filename = time() . $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move('img/products', $filename);

             $product->images->updateOrCreate(['id' => $key], ['name' => $filename]);
        }
    }
```

Please Not that i assume that $key is id iamges means your input should be named like this

```
<imput name="images['Id_of_image_in_databse']" type="file" />
```

Comment: that why i first asked you to provide your code for form

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure about code result, place below code before `if ($request->hasFile('images')) {` line:

```
print('<pre style="color:red;">Uploaded image:: ');
print_r($request->file('images'));
print('</pre>');


print('<pre style="color:red;"> Product Image:: ');
print_r($product->images);
print('</pre>');
exit;
```

This is not but part of answer! So let me know the result from above code.